# ERB scope: instance variable vs locals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, erb

Suppose I have a controller with an `index` action and I would like to pass some data into the action's view (`index.html.erb`).

Typically, the rails way is to do: `@some_var = some_value`.

Does the above add to the global scope in a sense that `@some_var` is now available everywhere (helpers, etc...)? If so, is it better to do something like `locals: {some_var: some_value}` instead?

What are the tradeoffs if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `@some_var` is "global" in the sense that it added to the view context that is shared by views and helpers. So your controller, view, partials, and helpers can all access the same `@some_var`.

Using instance variables like this is the Rails convention: they just appear "like magic" in your views and helpers with no additional code. For simplicity, I would recommend it for most projects, especially as you are starting out.

However as your Rails app grows, here are some other best practices to keep in mind:

- Try to limit your controller to assigning only one instance variable. If you find yourself assigning many instance variables in a single controller action, that is usually a sign that your controller is trying to do too much.
- Avoid using instance variables in helpers. This makes your helper methods harder to reuse in other contexts, because they depend on instance variables being set "just right" by the controller. This can be a source of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you've got it. I prefer local arguments like that too, even though you're right Rails suggests you use instance variables.

I think instance variables may be okay when they are in a full template (never in a partial), and especially when you only have one of them that has the same name as the controller or whatever.

But in general, I agree with you. There is no downside to doing it with locals, unless you consider it confusing code, perhaps it would confuse someone who expects it to be the 'ordinary' Rails way.

I guess someone could argue that Rails templates are inherently tightly coupled to the controller, are meant to be that way, so it's no big deal to use instance variables -- the main negative of which is that it tightly couples your template to a particular controller implementation, but, they'd say, that's fine. I guess that's an opinion, apparently it is Rails' opinion!  Certainly plenty of apps are written that way, and it's fine.

But there isn't really anything that's going to get in your way from going against the typical Rails way of doing things, and using local template arguments instead of instance variables. It works fine. I've done it.

I think you are right to be willing to question Rails -- sometimes Rails has made some odd choices. And *also* right to be cautious about going ahead doing something differently than Rails seems to wants you to, sometimes it *does* cause problems. In this case, I don't expect it will.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, if you add `@some_var = some_value` to the index action then it will only be applied to that action. If you want to create a global action then you can apply it to the application.rb.

I highly recommend reading http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

but something that might interest you in specific is this:

> 4.4 default_url_options You can set global default parameters for URL generation by defining a method called default_url_options in your
>   controller. Such a method must return a hash with the desired
>   defaults, whose keys must be symbols:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base   def
default_url_options
    { locale: I18n.locale }  
end end
```

> These options will be used as a starting point when generating URLs,
>   so it's possible they'll be  overridden by the options passed in
>   url_for calls.
>
> If you define default_url_options in ApplicationController, as in the
>   example above, it would be used for all URL generation. The method can
>   also be defined in one specific controller, in which case it only
>   affects URLs generated there.